# Save & close workbook with current date as name

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new in VBA and I’m looking to automate a current process using VBA.

For every week of each month (Wednesday), I need to export an existing Excel template from Internet into a new workbook. This part is done but i would need to :

1. Save it like: "01 05 2018_With taxes_1889". I have so far found and adapted the code below which, when run once, creates a temporary file and save it into my folder but do not closed it automatically. 
   It would be great to have all download file saved with their related date in my folder.
2. I’m also willing to completely automate the process with a query which will launch the process each Wednesday of each week?

   ```
   Private Sub ADD_BTN_Click()
       Dim line As Integer
       Dim Ws As Worksheet
       Dim DBS As Database
       Dim RST As Recordset
       Dim SQL_TXT As String
       Dim COUNTRY_ID As Integer
       Dim DATE_FUEL As String
       Dim test As Boolean

   DownloadFile (LINK_FUEL) ' Download file on C:\TEMP
   Workbooks.Open (BUFFER_FILE)

   Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly Prices with taxes")

   datEfuel = Right(Ws.Cells(1, 12), 10)

   For line = 1 To 47
       If OPEN_DBS(DBS, FUEL_DB) Then
           SQL_TXT = "SELECT * FROM COUNTRY_DATA WHERE COUNTRY_NAME LIKE '" & Ws.Cells(line, 1).Value & "'" ' Search Country name

           If OPEN_RST(DBS, RST, SQL_TXT) Then
               COUNTRY_ID = RST![COUNTRY_ID]
               RST.Close
               SQL_TXT = "SELECT * FROM FUEL_DATA WHERE COUNTRY_ID=" & COUNTRY_ID
               test = True
               If OPEN_RST(DBS, RST, SQL_TXT) Then
                   While Not RST.EOF
                     If RST![FUELDATA_DATE] = CDate(datEfuel) Then test = False
                     RST.MoveNext
                   Wend
                   RST.Close
               End If
               If test Then
                   SQL_TXT = "SELECT * FROM FUEL_DATA"
                   OPEN_NEW DBS, RST, SQL_TXT
                   RST![COUNTRY_ID] = COUNTRY_ID
                   RST![FUELDATA_DATE] = datEfuel
                   RST![FUELDATA_AUTOMOTIVE] = Ws.Cells(line, 8).Value
                   RST.Update
               End If

           End If
           DBS.Close
           End If


   Next line

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: You probably should remove the second part of your question, as a) it's not clear what's being asked, and b) the number of ways in which you could go about doing this could fill a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close and save the workbook with a specified name, you can call the [**Close** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-close-method-excel) on the [**Workbook** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-object-excel), with `True` as the first parameter to save changes, and the name under which you want to save the file as the second parameter:

```
Dim book As Workbook
...
book.Close True, "01 05 2018_With taxes_1889.xlsx"
```

The **Workbook** object is returned from the [**Workbooks.Open** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel):

```
'Instead of this:
'    Workbooks.Open (BUFFER_FILE)
'use this:
Set book = Workbooks.Open (BUFFER_FILE)
```

If you want to use the current date as the name of the file, you can use the [**Date**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/date-function) function:

```
book.Close True, Date & ".xlsx"
```

You may want to use a specific format for the date in the name; this can be done with the [**FormatDate**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/formatdatetime-function) function, which formats a date using a predefined set of date formats:

```
'Uses the long date format from the computer's regional settings
book.Close True, FormatDate(Date, vbLongDate) & ".xlsx"
```

or with the [**Format**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function, which allows for custom formatting:

```
book.Close True, Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
```

Note that this will save in the current folder of the application (usually the Documents folder), unless you specify the full path.

```
book.Close True, "C:\path\to\folder\" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
```

---

Excel doesn't provide facilities for scheduled tasks, which means you'll have to do one of the following:

- use the Windows Task Scheduler to start the task. In that case I would strongly suggest not tying the code to a specific workbook, but rather using VBScript under Windows Script Host.
- check each time the workbook (or whereever this VBA code is running from) is opened, and run the process under the appropriate conditions

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working. Do you know how I can have it saved with the date of the day?

Comment: @Aimé If this answer resolves your problem, you should accept it (by clicking on the green checkmark next to the answer). If the answer is useful, you should upvote it (by clicking on the up-arrow next to the answer).

Comment: @Aimé I've updated my answer to use **Close** instead of **SaveAs**; this will automatically close the workbook when finished.